# Find message from hash?

Tags: java, c, hash, md5

I recently read that MD5 is not secure because it can be traced within a small amount of time.

If I give only a fixed 512 bit data as input.
MD5 will give 128 bit hash (32 hex values)

If MD5 is flawed, then can anyone suggest the best way to reconstruct the 512 bit input, given the 128 bit hash?

(Side note: I badly want to implement this. Would C++ be a better choice for speed or Java for its inbuilt security packages?)

Comment: I think you misunderstand why people don't advice it -- it's not because it's easily reversible (it's entirely irreversible, or it'd be amazing for compression), it's because it's very cheap to compute and so a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) can be built up very cheaply.

Comment: Wouldn't there be 2^(512-128) possible 512-bit inputs for any one 128-bit hash?  There's no possible way to reverse any given hash in isolation if the only thing you know is that the input was 512 bits of random data.

Comment: 512 bits divided by 128 bits is four. So each MD5 hash could be expected to be returned for four different inputs of size 512 bits. Even if you could calculate the MD5 hash for every single input of 512 bits (and there are more than 1.3E154 of them) how would you know which of the matches was the original message and which were red herrings caused by hash collisions?

Comment: There are 2^128 possible 128-bit hashes, and there are 2^512 possible 512-bit blocks of data.  There has to be a LOT more than four possible 512-bit blocks of data for any one 128-bit hash.

Comment: Find a math guy to explain "pidgeohole principle" to you. There are 2 ** 384 (about 4x10**115) different 512-bit blocks that hash to the same MD5. Reversing isn't possible even in principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ** 384 (about 4x10**115) different 512-bit blocks that hash to the same MD5. Reversing isn't possible even in principle.

It *is* possible, however, to find *one* of those 4x10**115 blocks that produces the same MD5 as the block you want, and *that's* why it's considered insecure. For example, if you posted a file to the net along with an MD5 hash to verify its integrity, a hacker might be able to replace it with a different file with the same hash.

With a more secure hash like SHA256, even this wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is simple and fast algorithm especially when implemented using GPU, so it can be cracked by brute force that is why it is not 'secure'. 
But the typical context in which it is insecure is in the respect of passwords which have limited number of characters and their typical combinations (dictionary worlds)

For 512bit long message the brute force would take too long even with MD5, it is equivalent to 64 characters passwords, currently the brute force attack limit is around 10 characters.